# Create a pdf from a html page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, preg-match-all

I've to edited a WP plugin to create a PDF document from a html page.
I've to add a way to insert the images into pdf document.
A part of the plugin code is like this:

```
<div class="description"  style="margin:0 30px;">
            <?php
            $description = wpautop($this->data->description);
            $description = preg_replace("/\[[^\]]+\]/", '', $description);
            $description = explode('<p>', $description);
            foreach ($description as $value) {
                ?>

                <div class="pacchettino" style="padding-bottom: 20px;margin:0 30px;">
                    <?php 
                        echo $value 
                    ?>
                </div> 

            <?php
            }
            ?>

        </div>
```

In this way, only the text part is printed into the pdf document. I want to add the images also and I would to use the preg_match_all PHP function to extract the src attribute of every img tags in the following way:

```
<div class="description"  style="margin:0 30px;">
                <?php
                $description = wpautop($this->data->description);
                $match = preg_match_all('<img src=\"(*?)\">', $description, $match);

                $description = preg_replace("/\[[^\]]+\]/", '', $description);
                $description = explode('<p>', $description);
                foreach ($description as $value) {
                    ?>

                    <div class="pacchettino" style="padding-bottom: 20px;margin:0 30px;">
                        <?php 
                            echo $value 
                        ?>
                    </div> 

                <?php
                }
                ?>

            </div>
```

but $match is NULL.
How can I take the string of html code to extact the img tag?
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

with fpdf and PHP you could create a .pdf from HTML-Code